# FM transmitter won’t work. I need help with more gain, and current at the output

Tags: frequency-modulation, mixer, mixed-signal

I am trying to make an FM transmitter circuit using cascaded transistors.  My two input signals are from a microphone and from an 80 MHz crystal.

I’ve calculated a gain of 22 from the first stage and 318 from the second stage but I am not completely sure if I am even transmitting a signal. I see on the scope that I do have 80 MHz on the output but the signal is so small.

The goal is to get this signal pushed out to a monopole antenna.

I am using 2N3904 for the transistors and the power stage uses TIP31/32 with 914 diodes. Only one 12V supply. I need help trying to get enough gain so that it is recognizable to a receiver that I’m building.

[image]

Comment: Can you ask a specific question? Also there is a tool if you edit your question that you can draw schematics with that might look a little cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

As Justme said, you have have no oscillator.

On top of that, you have no modulator. Putting the audio and RF both into the input of a common emitter amplifier is probably not going to give you any appreciable frequency modulation.

Then you have what looks more like an audio amplifier. There are no tuned circuits, the output is complementary symmetry, and the output transistors have a transition frequency of around 3 MHz, so they're not going to amplify 80 MHz very well, if at all.

I would recommend doing some research into RF design, the ARRL Handbook is a good place to start.

Also, you're going to have to make sure any transmitter you build is legal.

Answer (score 2):

- The 2N3904 has an \$f_T\$ of 200 or 300 MHz -- I can't remember which, but the rule of thumb is that you want an \$f_T\$ of at least 10 times your operating frequency.
- You *could* squeeze a bit of gain out of those transistors, but your circuit looks like an audio circuit that's not taking transistor losses at frequency into account.  Looking at existing circuits and paying attention to why they're different from audio circuits would be a *Good Thing*.
- As mentioned, you're just attaching an amplifier to a crystal, with no apparent oscillator circuit.  The amplifier *may* be self-oscillating, but if it is it's just by luck.

  - When you're choosing transistors for your oscillator, an even *greater* ratio of \$f_T\$ to operating frequency is often chosen, although for a crystal oscillator things may work with \$f_T \ge 800 \mathrm{MHz}\$.
- The TIP31/TIP32 matched pair has an \$f_T\$ of **only 3 MHz**.  It's totally inadequate to this task.

Answer (score 1):

You have a 80 MHz crystal but no oscillator circuit to use it, so you don't have a 80 MHz signal anywhere in the circuit. So no gain will help unless you actually have a circuit that generates a 80 MHz signal with the crystal.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the schematic for the parts on the stripboard for my FM transmitter.

[image: parts]

My transmitter is soldered together on a stripboard with the strips cut to length.

[image: parts]

My circuit works perfectly and is heard on any good quality FM radio up to 1km away
or on a cheap FM radio across the street.

[image: FM transmitter]